# How to disable group of radio buttons in java

Tags: java, swing, validation, jradiobutton, buttongroup

Hello I am looking for a way to disable a radio buttons if textfield is empty.
My radio buttons called buttonGroup1(jbutton1,jbutton2,jbutton3,jbutton4) should be disabled if textfield is empty but I have no idea how to make if statment for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to place the buttons in an array...

```
JRadioButton[] buttons = new JRadioButton[]{jbutton1,jbutton2,jbutton3,jbutton4};
```

Determine the state you want the buttons to become...

```
boolean enabled = !textfield.getText().trim().isEmpty();
```

The iterate the array and change the state of the buttons...

```
for (JRadioButton btn : buttons) {
    btn.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```